# Is there a way to update my component dynamically without refreshing the page?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue component which builds the card up, and within that component is another component that I pass data to with a prop I currently use Swal to as a popup to add a new project to the database however when it finishes adding I have to refresh the page for the data to be visible. The entire reason I wanted to use vue was to not have to refresh the page to view updated data and I haven't been able to figure it out.

This is my Projects.vue

```js
   import ProjectItem from './Projects/ProjectItem.vue';
    export default {
        name: "Projects",
        components: {
            ProjectItem
        },
    data() {
            return {
                    projects: []
                }
        },
        methods: {
            getProjects () {
                axios.get('/api/projects').then((res) => {this.projects = res.data});
            },
            addProject() {
                Swal.queue([{
                title: 'Add a New Project?',
                html:
                    '<label for="name" style="color: #000;font-weight: 700">Project Name<input id="name" class="swal2-input"></label>' +
                    '<label for="description" style="color: #000;font-weight: 700">Project Description<textarea id="description" rows="5" cols="15" class="swal2-input"></textarea></label>',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Create Project',
                showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                preConfirm: (result) => {
                    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                        if (result) {
                            let name = $('#name').val();
                            let desc = $('#description').val();
                            axios.post('/api/projects', {title:name,description:desc})
                            .then(function(response){
                                Swal.insertQueueStep({
                                type: 'success',
                                title: 'Your project has been created!'
                                })
                                resolve();
                            })
                            .catch(function(error){
                                Swal.insertQueueStep({
                                type: 'error',
                                title: 'Something went wrong.'
                                })
                                console.log(error);
                                reject();
                            })
                        }
                    });
                }
                }])
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            this.getProjects();
        }
```

I bind it to ProjectItem in my Project.vue template:

```
            <div class="table-responsive border-top">
                <table class="table card-table table-striped table-vcenter text-nowrap">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Project Name</th>
                            <th>Team</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Preview</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                        <project-item v-bind:projects="projects" />
                </table>
```

and this is my ProjectItem.vue:

```js
<template>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="project in projects" :key="project.id">
            <td>{{ project.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ project.title }}</td>
            <td><div class="avatar-list avatar-list-stacked">
                    {{ project.description }}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="text-nowrap">{{ project.updated_at }}</td>
            <td class="w-1"><a href="#" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "ProjectItem",
    props: ["projects"],
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must insert the recently added project to the products array.

If you are able to change the backend code, you could change the response to include the project.

```
this.projects.push(response.project);
```

Comment: Heres how I retrieve the data from the backend:
```
    public function index(Project $project)
    {
        $projects = Project::latest('created_at')->limit(5)->get();

        return response()->json($projects);
    }
```

Comment: @Riley Instead of just limiting your results to 5, maybe you can paginate them so you are able to grab groups of them and just increment the page to get the next set.

Comment: @Riley I believe you don’t need to make another call to retrieve projects data. Would you mind sharing what is in the response object? If this object contains the project you can just add it to the array. If it doesn’t, you could change your store method (assuming you are using Laravel resource controller) to return the new project in the response.

Comment: @ThiagoBarcala This is my response data object: 
data: {title: "ddd", description: "ddd"} & when I try to  this.projects.push(response.data); I get a referenceError: projects is not defined

Comment: @Riley that’s because of the way “this” is bound in JavaScript. Add `var self = this` as the first line of the function addProject, then use `self.projects.push(response.data)`. It might give you some errors though, because your project objects seem to require an id, which is not in your response data, so you might need to change the backend to include it.

Comment: @ThiagoBarcala It still just gives me a reference projects is not defined error